# jQuery Image Swap hover out

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to achieve an image swap effect and can't seem to get it to swap back to the original image without it jumping (Sliding out, in, out, in...)  What's the best way to accomplish this?

```
<ul id="carousel"> 
   <li class="carousel-img">
       <img class="defaultImg" src="/design-engine-blue.jpg">
       <img class="largeImg" src="/design-engine.jpg"> <!-- Larger in size then the default image -->

  </li>
  <li class="carousel-img">
       <img class="defaultImg" src="/design-engine-blue.jpg">
       <img class="largeImg" src="/design-engine.jpg">

  </li>
 </ul>
```

jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

        jQuery('.carousel-img').hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).children('.defaultImg').stop().hide("fast"); 
            jQuery(this).children('.largeImg').show("fast");
         }, function() {
             jQuery(this).children('.largeImg').hide("fast");
             jQuery(this).children('.defaultImg').show("fast");

        });
    }); //ready
```

CSS

```
#carousel li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    position: relative;
}

.largeImg {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say without more clarity on what "jumping" means, but you probably need to call `hover` on the `LI.carousel-img` rather than on the `.defaultImg` because the image is being hidden, which will inherently make it stop being hovered.

Comment: Is it 'jumping' because you are have .hide() with no speed on the first image and .show("fast") on the 2nd? I would imagine this would make the first image disappear instantly, but then have the 2nd image fade in. Also, can you please post your CSS? It may be because both images appear side by side for a moment, ruining your layout

Comment: I'm guessing you have two images, one over another and you want to show the bottom photo when you hover over the original (top) photo? We need to see your css.

Answer (score 1):

use css along with your jQuery. I'm assuming your photos are the same size. I'm using 100px as an example width and height

```
.largeImg{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
margin:0px;
display:none;
width:100px;
height:100px;
padding:0px;
}

.defaultImg{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
margin:0px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
padding:0px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.carousel-img').bind("mouseenter", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.defaultImg').hide();
    $this.find('.largeImg').show();
}).('.carousel-img').bind("mouseleave",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.largeImg').hide();
    $this.find('.defaultImg').show();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to note that the .largeImg is actually larger in size and is supposed to move the image next to it over slightly when hovered.